# terraform env: : No such file or directory

Tags: terraform

Cannot initialize the Terraform module or even check version.

```
$ ls
main.tf  output.tf  variables.tf
$ terraform --v
env: 22:58:10: No such file or directory
$ rm -rf .terraform && terraform init 
env: 23:43:38: No such file or directory
```

However, terraform is correctly installed

```
$ which terraform
/usr/local/bin/terraform
```

content of the terraform shell script

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/terraform
#!/bin/bash

#set -x
DEFAULT_VERSION="0.12.24"

if [[ -z "$VERSION" ]]; then
        TF_VERSION="$DEFAULT_VERSION"
else
    TF_VERSION="$VERSION"
fi

VADDR=$(grep 'provider "vault"' *.tf --exclude-dir=modules -A2 | grep -P --color -o '(?<=address = ")(.*)(?=")')
if [ -n "$VADDR" ]; then
  #echo "got vault addr $VADDR"
  VAULT_CONFIG="VAULT_TOKEN=$(unset VAULT_TOKEN && VAULT_ADDR=$VADDR viq tokengen)"
  #echo "got vault token $VAULT_CONFIG"
else
  VAULT_CONFIG="dummyfoo=dummybar"
fi

env $VAULT_CONFIG /opt/terraform/v${TF_VERSION}/terraform $@ 2>&1 | \
  sed -r -e 's/([ ]+)result:([ ]+)"[[:alnum:][:punct:]]+" => \
  <computed>/\1result:\2<redacted> => <computed>/' \
  -e 's/([ ]+)MasterUserPassword:([ ]+)"[^"]+"/\1MasterUserPassword:\2<redacted>/' \
  | sed -r -e 's/"10MySqlPassword".*/"10MySqlPassword" = "****" -> <redacted>/g' \
  | sed -r -e 's/API_KEY".*/API_KEY" = "****" -> <redacted>/g'
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: This is indeed a pretty confusing error. My guess would be that this is talking about the program called `env` that is available on most Unix systems which "runs a program in a modified environment". Is the name `terraform` on your system included in a shell alias, or is that `/usr/local/bin/terraform` a wrapper shell script rather than the Terraform binary itself?

Comment: Yes, env is the program to print current environment variables. terraform is not included in shell alias, it is a wrapper shell script.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to those reading this question if you could share the contents of your wrapper shell script. As far as I can tell, this error is coming from that shell script, rather than from Terraform itself.

Comment: Sure. Updated in the question description.

Comment: I'm not sure what that `viq tokengen` program you're running does, but my guess is that along with the token you're expecting it's also printing out a log line (or similar) starting with a timestamp like `23:43:38` that is then being included as part of `$VAULT_CONFIG`, and then `env` is interpreting that timestamp as the command to run.

Comment: ```viq tokengen``` is to generate token for authentication with VAULT. the ```VAULT_CONFIG``` does start with a timestamp like ```2020-04-06 18:18:33 Z [ERROR]```. But it doesn't explain everything since I can still run the terraform command in a neighbor module with the same VAULT_CONFIG output ```$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.24
+ provider.aws v2.55.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.random v2.2.1
+ provider.tls v2.1.1
+ provider.vault v2.9.0```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`. The `$PATH` `env` variable tells your system where to look for installed files.

```sh
$ echo $PATH
```

If it is not in your `$PATH`, then add the directory to your `$PATH`.

```sh
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Add the above line to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent) file to persist the change.

If it is in your path, then see if `terraform` is working by trying to check the version while specifying the full path of the executable.

```sh
$ /usr/local/bin/terraform --v
```

Comment: Thanks! 

My $PATH var already include the installation path


```$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/atlantiq/.local/bin:/home/atlantiq/bin```



I also tried with full path, Still see the same issue


```$ /usr/local/bin/terraform --v
env: 02:40:08: No such file or directory```

Comment: Moreover, another module under the same parent directory has terraform correctly configured.

Comment: I used to manually delete some auto-scaling groups provisioned by this module, probably the reason behind this issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, they helped me in my set up.
However on my side, there was a bit different situation.

- System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS,
- InteliJ: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition),
- tfenv: 2.2.3-71-g1ccfddb,
- and using ZSH,

while installing tfenv, I used needed to use [manual installation](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv#manual), and redirect PATH export to  `~/.zshrc` instead `~/.bash_profile`.
`terraform` command was working fine for me.

But did mistake on IDE config. `Terraform executable path` setting. I needed to point exact binary file (`.tfenv/bin/terraform`) instead directory only (`.tfenv/bin`). Stupid mistake, mayby it will help some others :D